# odoo base accounting kit payment_render javascript payment_matching xml congrats message

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, accounting

[error in output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aodKk.png)javascript code

'        showRainbowMan: function (state) {
if (this.model.display_context !== 'validate') {
return
}
var dt = Date.now()-this.time;
var $done = $(qweb.render("reconciliation.done", {
'duration': moment(dt).utc().format(time.getLangTimeFormat()),
'number': state.valuenow,
'timePerTransaction': Math.round(dt/1000/state.valuemax),
'context': state.context,
}));
$done.find('*').addClass('o_reward_subcontent');
$done.find('.button_close_statement').click(this._onCloseBankStatement.bind(this));
$done.find('.button_back_to_statement').click(this._onGoToBankStatement.bind(this));
// display rainbowman after full reconciliation
if (session.show_effect) {
this.trigger_up('show_effect', {
type: 'rainbow_man',
fadeout: 'no',
message: $done,
});
this.$el.css('min-height', '450px');
} else {
$done.appendTo(this.$el);
}
},
'

xml code
'

```
<h2>Congrats, you're all done!</h2>
<p>You reconciled <strong><t t-esc="number"/></strong> transactions in <strong><t t-esc="duration"/></strong>.
    <t t-if="number > 1">
        <br/>That's on average <t t-esc="timePerTransaction"/> seconds per transaction.
    </t>
</p>
<t t-if="context &amp;&amp; context.active_model">
    <p t-if="context['active_model'] === 'account.journal' || context['active_model'] === 'account.bank.statement' || context['active_model'] === 'account.bank.statement.import'" class="actions_buttons">
        <t t-if="context.journal_id">
            <button class="button_back_to_statement btn btn-secondary" t-att-data_journal_id='context.journal_id'>Go to bank statement(s)</button>
        </t>
        <t t-if="context['active_model'] === 'account.bank.statement'">
            <button class="button_close_statement btn btn-primary" style="display: inline-block;">Close statement</button>
        </t>
    </p>
</t>
```

'

congrate message shows "Congrats,you are all done!<.h2>...."
comment the part"$done," fix it partially

Comment: Please add questions clearly, There's too much code and not exactly sure what you are looking for

Comment: module base accounting kit 15 at app store
after payment matching and reconsliation it give wrong text output

Comment: i add picture of error